# In codeigniter, After login if I click the browser back button, I got back to the login page

Tags: codeigniter

I have created a login page where my first line is if session->userdata() exist then redirect to home. But after login when I click the back button, I get back to the login page. I expected that my session check will work but it's not, any help?

Answer (score 2):

i think this may help you.

add this in to your controller function to prevent caching of previous page

```
header("cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```